# How to save multiple plots from one MATLAB GUI axes as an image?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, jpeg

In my MATLAB GUI the user loads an image to axes1 and then adds plots onto it (using "hold on").
After that, I want to save the entire image, with all the plots on top (in either format, jpg, bmp, it doesn't really matter that much).

I have tried:

```
Image = getimage(handles.axes1);
imwrite(Image,[Directory Filename '_marked.bmp']);
```

but this saves only the original image, without the plots on top of it.

I have also tried:

```
F = getframe(handles.axes1);
Image = frame2im(F);
```

which works, but really saves a screenshot of the axes area. The problem with this is that if by any chance the user has zoomed-in on the image and left the display zoomed-in, this saves the zoomed-in display instead of the full image.

Is there any way to retrieve all the data in axes1 at once and as an image?

Thank you very much,

Noga

Comment: Try to apply `zoom out` before saving with `getframe`.

Comment: `saveas(figureHandle,'FigureName.png')` will save you a nice `png` file of the drawing area of the figure (=figure minus the menubar and toolbar). You can change `png` to a variety of format. And as Matt said, zoom out before you save.

Comment: Thank you both for responding.

I just realized the what may be the reason for that saveas leaves out the extra plots on top of the image; I have created another handle for each plot so that I would be able to remove it if necessary. 

    zoom out;
    F = getframe(handles.axes1);
    Image = frame2im(F);
    imwrite(Image,[Directory Filename '_marked.bmp']);

works perfectly!


Thanks again.